# Error in ZMQ's poller.ipp when trying to compile

Tags: c++, macos, zeromq

When trying to compile my c++ project the compiler exits with an error in ZMQ's poller.ipp. Am I doing something wrong, do I need additional compiler flags or something?

I have installed the c++ binding (czmqp++) using `brew install czmqpp`

System: Mac OSX 10.11.5

This is the output when I am trying to compile with the following command:

```
> gcc -Wall -o HardwareHub HardwareHub.cpp

In file included from HardwareHub.cpp:4:
In file included from ./ZMQCommunicator.h:3:
In file included from /usr/local/include/czmq++/czmqpp.hpp:28:
In file included from /usr/local/include/czmq++/poller.hpp:48:
/usr/local/include/czmq++/impl/poller.ipp:29:19: error: expected expression
    auto unmask = [](socket& s)
                  ^
1 error generated.
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the c++ compiler, not the c compiler:

> ```
> > gcc -Wall -o HardwareHub HardwareHub.cpp
> ```

should be

```
> g++ -Wall -o HardwareHub HardwareHub.cpp
```

---

In case your currently installed GCC version doesn't support the current c++ standard use

```
> g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -o HardwareHub HardwareHub.cpp
```

Comment: Oh thanks, I thought it would be an easy one like that.